# Queue set usage in Free RTOS

Tags: queue, rtos, freertos

In Free RTOS, my task has to wait for 3 different events. So, what I have done is, in the ISR, I will send the data through the queue from 3 different events. And if any of the queue gets written, the tsak will be unblocked. Also each of this queue can be overwritten,i.e. atmost one event will be filled in the queue. So, now the question is, how can I unblock a single task based on data from 3 queues?
I have seen QueueSet(). Is it good to use that?

Answer (score 0):

`QueueSet` is the only solution to wait on 3 queues. But I think you can have a solution to wait on only one queue, which is simpler. You just have to create a structure which contain a code for the event type and a union to store each data:

```
enum EventType
{
    Event1,
    Event2,
    Event3
};

struct EventMessage
{
    enum EventType event;
    union
    {
        int paramEvent1;
        char paramEvent2;
        unsigned char paramEvent3[4];
    } parameters;
};

void sendEvent1(...)
{
    struct EventMessage msg;
    msg.event = Event1;
    msg.parameters.paramEvent1 = ...;

    xQueueSend(queue, &msg, portMAX_DELAY); //or xQueueSendFromISR if is in ISR
}

// Same for event2 and 3, replacing "msg.event = " with correct code
// And set correct parameters

void task(void * cookie)
{
    struct EventMessage msg;

    for(;;)
    {
        xQueueReceive(queue, &msg, portMAX_DELAY);
        switch(msg.event)
        {
            case Event1:
                //manage event1
                break;
            case Event2:
                //manage event2
                break;
            case Event3:
                //manage event3
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) . The problem I have is all 3 events are independent and can occur multiple times before I could process the event in the foreground. Also I would be content with the latest state of the event. So, I would be using [Queue Overwrite] (http://www.freertos.org/xQueueOverwrite.html). So, with your solution, i.e. using a single queue and sending the event inline, one of my event may get overwritten. Also am new Stack overflow. Sorry for my bad formatting.

Comment: @user2717596 So you have to use 3 queues with `QueueSet` ;)

Comment: "the only solution" - not really; the function can be (and probably is) built from lower-level OS primitives.  For example, you can block on an event flags group, where each flag indicates which queue contains a message.  The sender places the message in the appropriate queue and sets the corresponding event flag  That is how you would do in an RTOS that does not have an equivalent to QueueSet.  Of the OS does not support even flags, you could use a semaphore and no-wait-poll the queues.  There is always another solution.  On FreeRTOS however these methods are likely to be rather inefficient.

Comment: That's right, I totally forgot [Event groups](http://www.freertos.org/event-groups-API.html) functionality. I will do an update as soon as I have time